# SOAP UI test suites - set property with value inside tag

Tags: groovy, soapui

I can easily set property in Property step for following line:

```
<(tagName)>111<(/tagName)>
```

just by modifying line as:

```
<(tagName)>${Properties#PropertyName}<(/tagName)>
```

where Properties is a step in testSuite with names and values.

But how I can do this for such row: `<(city cityNumber="111")>`

and for such: `<(Request requestType="TEXT" versionNumber="VERSION")>`?

I just want to write those properties in my Properties table.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear as to what you are trying to convert from/to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I do not understand the round brackets - what is that suppose to be?

You would do it the same way:

```
<city cityNumber="${Properties#PropertyName}">
<Request requestType="${Properties#PropertyText}" versionNumber="${Properties#PropertyVersion}">
```

SoapUI, when it internally goes the through the property expansion phase, it treats everything as String. Only after the message gets transmitted to your server, does it get treated as XML.

Documented on [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html).

Comment: strange formatting... do not mention that brackets.